# Unable to use SLDS Icons in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-design-system, lightning-web-components

I am developing an app and I need to add SLDS icon with custom color (i.e. green or blue) to the UI.
Which is why I can't use `<lightning-icon>` component because you can override it style.

Thus I tried tu use a bare SLDS Svg with the folowing markup :

```html
<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-comments">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill: #3496ec" class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true">
           <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#comments"></use>
      </svg>
</span>
```

However the icon is not rendered and I have a 404 not found error in the console about the icon's link.

Any idea about that ?

Answer (score 12):

Change "/assets" to "/_slds" in the use element.

```
<use xlink:href="/_slds/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#comments"></use>
```

Comment: I just tested and it doesn't work in my case

Comment: I can confirm this works in Winter 2020. My example: `<use xlink:href="/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check"></use>`

Comment: This works with Edge

Comment: Still working in Winter 2022