# Lightning Web Security breaks LWC with svg use tag

Tags: lightning-web-components, security

When there is a LWC using `svg` `use` tag like suggested on [Lightning design system site](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/icons/) and `Lightning Web Security` is turned on (the setting `Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components on Session Settings`), it breaks LWC with an error

```
Error during LWC component connect phase: [String.prototype.startsWith called on null or undefined]
```

Listing of example component

```
<template>
    Web Security
    <lightning-combobox
        label="Select"
        options={svgOptions}
        onchange={handleSelection} >
    </lightning-combobox>

    <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true">
        <use xlink:href={svg}></use>
    </svg>
</template>
```

Listing of example JS file

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class WebSecurity extends LightningElement {

    svgOptions = [{label:'Utility',value:'/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#notification'},{label:'Standard & Custom',value:'/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account'}];

    handleSelection(event) {
        this.svg = event.detail.value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update (as of 11th May 2022):

[Salesforce has confirmed the bug and opened known issue.](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p4V00000210qN)

Details below.

I have opened a case in Salesforce support.

There is some issue in the `aura_proddebug.js:14475:12` and `aura_prod.js:49:2828`

```
    StringStartsWith()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs92/auraFW/javascript/2yRFfs4WfGnFrNGn9C_dGg/aura_proddebug.js:14475:12
    sanitizeSvgHrefValue()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs92/auraFW/javascript/2yRFfs4WfGnFrNGn9C_dGg/aura_proddebug.js:15663:9
    Object.value [as sanitizeAttribute]()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs92/auraFW/javascript/2yRFfs4WfGnFrNGn9C_dGg/aura_proddebug.js:34752:18
```

aura_prod.js

```
tt()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs92/auraFW/javascript/2yRFfs4WfGnFrNGn9C_dGg/aura_prod.js:49:2828
pi()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs92/auraFW/javascript/2yRFfs4WfGnFrNGn9C_dGg/aura_prod.js:78:1359
Object.value [as sanitizeAttribute]()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs92/auraFW/javascript/2yRFfs4WfGnFrNGn9C_dGg/aura_prod.js:100:134492
```

Comment: This may fit best as an edit to your original post until you hear back from support

Comment: @nbrown I finally received confirmation from SF Support

Answer (score 2):

I quickly reproduced this on what you shared - but, I had no issue with this code once I added a check to make sure `svg` is not null as I assume it has no value initially.

```html
<template if:true={svg}>
    <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true">
        <use xlink:href={svg}></use>
    </svg>
</template>
```

The above prevents the error, but to display the icons you'll also want to update your links to use `_slds` vs. `asset` in the path. Noted in some [other](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294170/what-is-the-path-to-lightning-svg-icons-in-a-sandbox) [answers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265030/unable-to-use-slds-icons-in-lightning-web-component).

```js
svgOptions = [
    {
        label:'Utility',
        value:'/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#notification'
    },
    {
        label:'Standard Custom',
        value:'/_slds/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account'
    }
];
```

You can also consider using [lightning-icon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-icon/example) instead and dynamically switching the `icon-name`.

Comment: let me check your workaround

Comment: actually, yes, as a workaround we might either wrap this under template if:true or use svg = ''. Actually in fact we are using static resource in real issue, so I can't use lightning-icon there, I tried here to simplify the definition of problem, so I removed the references to the static resource and replaced them by references to standard SLDS icons. Still, it shouldn't fail since it doesn't fail when LWC Web Security is turned off.

Comment: Figured it was simplified. I disagree whether we know it "shouldn't fail since it doesn't fail when LWC Web Security is turned off". Support can answer that question or if this is expected based on the differences with what LWS does.

Comment: I expect from SF Support to confirm, but it might take months to receive actual confirmation from them

Comment: Finally I have received confirmation from SF Support